# bootstrap 5 modal returns to calling method before the modal-popup buttons are clicked

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal, blazor-webassembly

My project is Blazor WASM-hosted, .Net 6, C#, VS-2022, **Bootstrap v5**.  I have coded up a blazor component <MessageBoxComponent ... > to handle the modal-html and button-click-code to hide/terminate the popup.  I have got so far that it works like a js-"alert()"-function in that the text and buttons are displayed and clicking a button returns the "button-number" of the clicked button which is also correct.  The launching of this modal-popup occurs in the "handle-submit" click of my Blazor CRUD component (not a page) -- code follows:

```
public async Task HandleSubmit() {
    // --- other code --- //
    refMessageBox.DoShow();  <- NOTE: I expect this to be MODAL, but it is NOT modal, it returns immediately.
    switch (MsgBoxReturnedValue) {
        case 1:
        // --- continue with SAVE code --- //
        await OnSavedCRUD.InvokeAsync(kvPairAction);
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
    // --- other code --- //    
}
```

The "DoShow()" code within the modal-component follows:

```
public void DoShow() {
    _IsShow = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

The event returned back after user selects a button in the modal-popup code follows:

```
void MessageBoxReturnChanged(int pButtonPressed) {
    // Event coming from MessageBoxComponent.
    MsgBoxReturnedValue = pButtonPressed;
    switch (pButtonPressed) {
        case 1:
        // --- continue with SAVE code --- //
        await OnSavedCRUD.InvokeAsync(kvPairAction);
        break;
    
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

What happens in the HandleSubmit-function is the call to `refMessageBox.DoShow();` returns immediately and therefore there is no way to act upon the user's button-click from the modal-component, since the click-event occurs after the calling function is finished.

I am missing some technique? -- do I need javascript functions to control the events of the modal-popup?  Your questions, comments and answers are welcome...thanks...John

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by making the modal show as `async` function which return a task and use it by `await`. As you may know Blazor WAsm is a single thread process and it waits for your answer to be returned. for example use this simple Prompt version of your modal (where `message` is get from user):

```
private async Task showPrompt()
    {
        message = await _js.Prompt(message);
    }
```

where:

```
function showPrompt(message) {
    return prompt(message, 'Type anything here');
    }
```

Also be sure to hide your modal at the end of your form submission.

Comment: Thank you @Mehdi... Please clarify for me what you mean by "Prompt()" and "message".  I have neither in my code set.  What I get from your answer is I should do is at the point where I have set up the MessageBoxComponent and am ready to "refMessageBox.DoShow();  <- NOTE: I expect this to be MODAL, but it is NOT modal, it returns immediately.", I should send this to local task with async.  Then inside this new function, I should await the "refMessageBox.DoShow()" function as coded above. Upon return from that "await" I return to my calling function and process the button-click. Please confirm.

Comment: change your code in a way that your submit button shows the modal (DoShow) and the button of modal for real submiting the form.